# node.js + object key value appending

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

In my node application i am running 2 sequelize queries and getting 2 object array as output. Now i have to append 1 key value from 2nd object array to the first.

Consider the following are the 2 object array:

```
1st
[{"id_0":56,
  "id_1":67,
  "staterank":32},
{"id_0":87,
  "id_1":97,
  "staterank":5}
]

2nd array:
[{"id_0":56,
  "id_1":67,
  "countryrank":140},
{"id_0":87,
  "id_1":97,
  "countryrank":400}
]

The array needed by me:
[{"id_0":56,
  "id_1":67,
  "staterank":32
  "countryrank":140},
{"id_0":87,
  "id_1":97,
  "staterank":5
  "countryrank":400}
]
```

I tried for the following code:

```
2ndarray.forEach(function(countryelem){
            1sttarray.forEach(function(stelem){                
                    console.log("countryelem=" + util.inspect(countryelem));
                stelem.countryrank = countryelem.country_rank;
                })    
            })
```

But i am receiving coumtrycode as "1" which is the last entry in 2nd array.Please help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..